# Is it possible to dispatch an operation from different threads to main thread in a console C# application?

Tags: c#, .net

This is more of a knowledge thing. I just wanted to know whether its possible or not. And would be helpful to give also justification to either case.

Since someone thought they need more explaination and held my question. So here for them

Basically the scenario which I am trying to tackle is that. I have a console app which has an API to call to Native code (with lot of global state) and only one thread could call the native code in a given time.

My console app launches multiple thread doing lot of calculations while they want to call Native code also within them.

Now I have following doubts or could be my lack of understanding (please excuse)

1. If I use lock{} to each native calls then I can stop only one thread going to the core thats good, but just imagine if THREAD 1 and THREAD 2 waiting for the lock then who gets the lock first? is it the First come first serve or whether its in-deterministic?
2. If its in-deterministic then I would want to dispatch all my calls for Native API from different thread to be dispatched to the main console app running thread.

Comment: See msdn BackgroundWorker.  You can use the ProgressChange Event : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx.  Progreechanged evnet can be use to send messages as well as updating a progress bar.

Comment: @jdweng That wouldn't marshal callbacks to the main thread when there is no message loop.

Comment: No UI here. So no event message loop

Comment: Your response doesn't make any sense.  An event is an event so you don't need a loop to send a message.  You can design a thread any way you like and using a ProgressChange to send message can alway be used.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for correcting I was not aware that BackgroungWorker could be used in a console app as well.

Comment: The main thread needs a block in a console application so it doesn't terminate.  Usually I use a WaitOne() for the block which will keep main thread in a sleep mode and only respond to events.  A form project has a built in block in the base form class so the form doesn't terminate.

Answer (score 2):

possible? sure thing ... as long as you define something as a main thread ...
since by default there is no message loop you'd have to make something up, or get a reference to winforms Application class or WPFs dispatcher, and fire one of those up ... they should work regardless of the fact that there is no winforms or wpf ui if you start them

if you have code in your application that needs certain operations to be done on a certain thread ... why not dispatch things to the right thread?

Comment: Main thread here I meant the main console app thread. So in my console app I launch multiple thread and my console app has functions which call native code. Now I want to dispatch different operations to the main thread which are calling these native functions.

Comment: @Sherry easiest way to go is to first instanciate one winforms Control and have the reference available for the other threads (like a `static Control foo`) and then start the winforms messageloop with `Application.Run()` when your main thread has brought everything up. from another thread you can then call `foo.Invoke(...)` or `foo.BeginInvoke(...)`